# What is the requirement of empty loop in python code ? Can we use the function or loop if we use "pass" keyword in it

Tags: python, loops

```
for letter in 'worldcup': 
    pass
print 'Last Letter :', letter
```

Will this loop make sense in our code? What is the need of writing empty loop or function in the code?
Please be kind to pardon me if asked something silly. I am a newbie. 
Thank You

Comment: If you're asking "will this code run?", I recommend that you run it and see :-)

Comment: You can run It by yourself. I don't get what you want

Comment: Thank You! I have run the code and checked the output. But I wish to know that what is the requirement of empty loop or function in our code.

Comment: Remove the loop and you'll see.

Comment: `...what is the requirement of empty loop or function in our code` : we don't know what your requirement is, why did you write it that way?

Comment: Why do you need a loop that does nothing but `pass` inside it? If you just want the last letter, you can use string methods on "worldcup" to access the last letter directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may use the pass statement for an empty for loop. Pass is considered as a dummy statement. You may find some details [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-write-an-empty-function-in-python-pass-statement/)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work as a loop? Yes.

Does this work to get the last letter of the string? Also yes.

However the best way to do what you are doing in the example is to index from the back.

```
>>> string = 'worldcup'
>>> last_letter = string[-1]
>>> last_letter
p
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> for i in [1,2,3]:
...     pass
... 
>>> i
3
>>>
```

You mean like this? Yes, it will run.